# Flash flickers on IE page and mozilla displays white background

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a flash swf file which is published as adobe air file because im using the FileStream libraries. It seems that when i remove the FileStream code the flash swf file works on the HTML page but when i revert back to add the FileStream libraries and code the flash flickers in IE 8 and Mozilla displays a Blank screen. Why is this?

Thanks for any replies in advance.

Here is the code:

```
import flash.filesystem.*;

var url:String = "C:/New Folder/image.mp3";
var file:File = new File(url);
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.openAsync(file, FileMode.APPEND);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use FileStream in IE or other web browsers, it is only for use in installed AIR applications.

You can't use a "swf file which is published as adobe air file" in a web page. The idea behind AIR is that it is a separate runtime, for locally installed applications. This makes it possible to do thinks that is not allowed from a web page in a browser.

In the documentation for ActionScript, it is specified what runtimes support what, sor for example for FileStream it says "Runtime Versions: AIR 1.0", while it would say for example "Runtime Versions: AIR 1.0, Flash Player 9" for the [flash.net.FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) that can be used in both AIR and Flash Player in a browser.

Comment: the only problem is that i cant primary write to a file and append new contents to that file using filereference. And i dont want to open a dialog box. Is there another way?

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure you can't write to the file system from a web page without a user dialog, for security reasons.